# Storing user data in session store or retrieving from database in each request in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

I am migrating the my old ASP.NET Web Forms project to ASP.NET Core Web API and Frontend Angular. in my older application storing user information instace and it's values(like assigned groups,permissions,and other user information).i am going to use JWT i can't store all information in JWT,so should i continue session in my asp.net core application or retrieve this information from database in each request?

Is there any other Best practices are available in modern application development?

Comment: The [Session and State Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state) docs already explain this. Unless you have a very small web app, you'll be using multiple servers anyway so you'll have to use [distributed  session storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0) backed by a database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for you comment. I have read the docs. i have almost 5K users i am going to use JWT for authentication, but in current system i am storing permission and other user related information in session should i remove session and retrieve this information from database in each request that increase database calls

Comment: On the other hand, *roles* aren't session state, they're [authorization properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Their storage is handled by the authorization middleware, not session management. If you use claims authentication, only the claims should go into the JWT, not the entire user profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple options for this, depending on what you need:

1. Angular cache. If the data is not sensitive, you can use the [rxjs observables](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html) to cache some data on the application side. Nothing wrong with some data stored on the browser. Since you are coming from a full postback application, the SPA caching is most times equivalent to old `Session` object.
2. Depending on the implementation you might need some cache on the server side too. Since as mentioned you'll have multiple servers, I'd suggest only caching lookups and such, not user related data. If you implement stickyness with servers and sessions (not recommended), this is still an option.
3. Distributed cache. You might have heard of Redis and such? This is also an option to store cache data to a third service, accessible by all server instances.

It all comes down to complexity vs speed. If the queries are simple enough and lightning fast, then it might be useless to store them in any cache anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have choice for distributed cache. i want to restrict the Web API Endpoints. should i store number of assigned permission in session(and i have other information too)? or retrieve from database for each request which one is more feasible